# Cannot Resolve Constructor when intends to redirect an Activity

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-intent, android-recyclerview

Hi guys ive been wanting to open to another activity when any of the item within the recycler view has been clicked or pressed. And when i declaring the intent like this it gave me this error

> Cannot resolve constructor 'Intent(com.example.fyptest1.RoomAdapter,
> java.lang.Class<com.example.fyptest1.staffSpecificRoomActivity>)'

**This here is the code**

```
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View viewer) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(RoomAdapter.this,staffSpecificRoomActivity.class);
        }
    });
```

**And when i change to "this" it gave me error as well, my program is not using fragment so getApplication context is not usable right?**

> Cannot resolve constructor 'Intent(anonymous
> android.view.View.OnClickListener,
> java.lang.Class<com.example.fyptest1.staffSpecificRoomActivity>)'

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,staffSpecificRoomActivity.class);
```

Comment: You can pass the context to your Adapter class, so you can use it inside the intent,

Comment: Did Joshua Tabi's answer help?

Comment: yesy yess it doess, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this "viewer" to the line of code and ure good to go

```
Intent intent = new Intent(viewer.getContext(),staffSpecificRoomActivity.class);
```